# How to use Map if I have to pass two values to uniquely identify a record?

Tags: apex

I have a custom object C (intersection object) which has two lookups.
One (C.A__c) to custom object A and another (C.B__c) to custom object B.
C also has a data field called Val__c

I would use Map structure if I am able to uniquely identify my record in C object but since I can identify my record in C object only by passing two (C.A__c, C.B__c) how can I use Maps here to retrieve my record in C ???

Comment: Why don't you just use a combination of these 2 values as a key? E.g. `C.A__c-C.B__c`. That's something I do to chec uniqueness by 2 fields

Comment: @blank There's a better way than string concatenation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an Sobject field as a key:

```
Map<someSObjType__c, someSObjType__c> uniqueValues = new someSObjType__c, someSObjType__c>();
```

To calculate a key:

```
someObjType__c key = new someObjType__c(Field1=someValue, Fiedl2=someValue);
```

This eliminates all possible bugs from using methods that include string concatenation:

```
// DO NOT DO THIS. DO NOT DO THIS. DO NOT DO THIS.
String key = record.FieldA__c+'-'+record.FieldB__c;
```

This method can be fooled, and while it would be rare to do intentionally, data can easily fool such a method. Using an sobject key prevents all false positives.

Comment: Yup, nice move. But could you please provide an example of false positives with string concatenation? I'm trying to figure this out, but I only see problems if Lookups look at the same object...

Comment: @blank If you only have ID values, should be safe, but the general rule is to use multiple fields, which prevents false positives. For example, if someone typed in a name with a `-`, your code could be subverted. Also, as previously noted in other questions, using SObject keys are about 50% faster in performance.

Comment: cool, didn't know about performance issues. Yup, I agree that non-Id fields should definitely be handled your way. Thanks showing this approach